# Android Build Error - 5.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am trying to build Android 5.1.1 (branch android-5.1.1_r14) for nexus 5. My build environment is based on Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed all the required packages. Before downloading the source code, I didn't download a fresh copy of `repo` (binary) as I had one from the last time I built (about a year ago).

I did the repo sync for the desired branch. After AOSP download, I downloaded and extracted the required binaries and generated the `vendor` folder. I am getting error when running lunch to prepare building for hammerhead:

```
Lunch menu... pick a combo:
 ....
 14. aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
 ....

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 14
build/core/envsetup.mk:162: no file name for `include'
build/core/envsetup.mk:173: Extraneous text after `else' directive
build/core/combo/select.mk:65: build/core/combo/TARGET_linux-.mk: No such file or directory
build/core/clang/config.mk:81: build/core/clang/TARGET_.mk: No such file or directory

** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_hammerhead'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

I did find on this [page](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html):

```
You may use Ubuntu 12.04 to build older versions of Android. Version 12.04 is not 
supported on master or recent releases.`
```

Is the above statement the reason for the lunch error or did I miss some other step ?

**Edit:**

I tried using the other lunch options. None of them work.

I also checked the `.repo` folder in the downloaded code. There is file `manifest.xml`, which contains the line:

```
<manifest>

  <remote  name="aosp"
       fetch=".." />
  <default revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r14"
       remote="aosp"
       sync-j="4" />
   .....
```

Did my decision of not using a fresh copy of repo binary possibly cause this problem ?

**Edit 2:**

I updated the `repo` binary, I did the resync and ran the `envsetup.sh` script. It still doesn't work. I tried downloading the code on a remote server I have (which is 14.04). I noticed that the lunch option sequence differs on that machine compared to my local 12.04 (`aosp_hammerhead-userdebug` is lunch option 21 on 14.04, while it was 14 on 12.04), even when the same repo binary is used and the same android branch is synced. The lunch and compilation work fine on my remote 14.04 server, but I need to do it on my local 12.04 to flash my device.

Comment: It says that you can use 12.04 on older versions of android, but **not** on master or recent releases. Also what did you clone?

Comment: If you're asking the repo sync command, I used the `b` option, with branch `android-5.1.1_r14` (from [list](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds))

Comment: I assume you tried resyncing? Also after resyncing did you re-run the environment script  (from root run . build/envsetup.sh) ?

Comment: I updated the `repo` binary, I did the resync and ran the `envsetup.sh` script. It still doesn't work. Looking into it. I tried downloading the code on a remote server I have (which is 14.04). I noticed that the lunch option sequence differs on that machine compared to my local 12.04, even when the same `repo` binary is used and the same android branch is synced.

Comment: The order in which the lunch targets being displayed will vary, that doesn't really tell us why it doesn't work.